# Integrating C++ libraries in C for ARToolKit - ARToolkit+

Tags: c++, c, augmented-reality, flartoolkit

I am working on a Augmented reality Project where I plan to use ARToolkit for Image Capturing and rendering where as ARToolKitPlus for marker detection.

The problem is ARToolKit is a C library where as ARToolKit+ is written in C++. Can some one please sugegst me a way to integrate them both.

[ARToolKit Library](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/)

[ARToolkitPlus](http://studierstube.icg.tu-graz.ac.at/handheld_ar/artoolkitplus.php)

Comment: Is ARToolKitPlus offline or is there any mirror anywhere? https://github.com/abandonware/artoolkitplus

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in C++ as it is able to call both C and C++ libraries.

In order for the C code to be callable from C++, any external names need to be qualified with `extern "C"`.  Normally the developer of the C library will put that in there for you, but if they didn't you can do outside your include:

```
extern "C" {
#include "c_header_file_missing_extern_c.h"
}
```